# What nuance does this have?

Tags: grammar

**Might it not be a mistake?**

I don't understand this combination, might plus not, this way.

Answer (score 2):

*[might](http://www.wordwebonline.com/search.pl?w=might)* expresses the possibility. Here, the speaker/author wants to express the possibility of whether it is a mistake.

Make this question an answer and it'll look fine to you -

> It might not be a mistake.

It's just formed into a question.

However, I'd rather say in this order- *Might not it be a mistake?*

Comment: +1 Yep. The question (and the statement you use as an example) also work with the word "not" deleted. In the statement you use, the use of the word "not" puts a greater emphasis on the possibility that *the thing* wasn't a mistake, perhaps it was intentional. That emphasis is somewhat less evident in the question (both as you form it and as written in the OP), even with the word "not".

Comment: So "might it not be a mistake?" or "it might be a mistake, might it not?" is a less direct way of saying " might it be a mistake?"

Answer (score 1):

The question "Might it not be?" is derived from the sentence "It might not be", by the process of [Subject-Aux inversion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subject%E2%80%93auxiliary_inversion).

The subject is "it", and the auxiliary verb is "might".  These two elements exchange places, and a question is formed.

"It might not be" expresses uncertainty about whether something may or may not be. The speaker is fairly certain that something is a certain way, but there is some doubt.

> I think I can fix the engine, but it might not be easy. [I'm quite confident about fixing it, but I foresee certain possible difficulties.]

The question "might it not be?" expresses the speaker's suspicion that something is true, or exists in a certain way. It is usually a rhetorical question, which has the effect of proposing the suspicion in a humble way.

> Might it not be that you're doing it wrong? [Is it possible you are doing it wrong?] -> [I suspect you're doing it wrong, but I want to say that in a nicer way.]